# replace -strings in python data frame

Tags: python, pandas

i want to replace a string to a number:

```
birds.priority=birds.priority.replace('yes' ,'1')
birds['priority']
```

my output is   :-

```
a    None
b    None
c    None
d    None
e    None
f    None
g    None
h    None
i    None
j    None
```

Comment: `birds.priority=birds.priority.str.replace('yes' ,'1')` if you are trying to replace sub string then use .`str`

Comment: Post a sample of `birds.priority`

Answer (score 0):

This code should solve your purpose.

```
birds.priority = birds.priority.str.replace('yes', '1', regex = True)

birds['priority']
```

**NOTE:** When pattern is a compiled regex, all flags should be included in the compiled regex. Use of case, `flags`, or `regex=False` with a compiled regex will raise an error.

When the given pattern is a string and `regex is True (the default)`, the given string is compiled as a regex. When replacement pattern is a string, it replaces matching regex patterns as with `re.sub()`.